# Implementation of the Linux utility tree, which prints out the subdirectory structure of the directory specified on the command line

Tags: c

I am getting an error inside Gradescope autograder 1.8) Deep directory tree (0/5)
Test Failed: Program segfaulted. The code correctly prints the path of the directory.

```
/* problem1.c - implementation of Linux `tree` */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_PATH_LEN 1024

void print_tree(const char *path, int indent) {
  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *entry;

  if (!(dir = opendir(path))) {
    perror(path);
    return;
  }

  while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
    /* skip hidden files and directories */
    if (entry->d_name[0] == '.')
      continue;

    /* print indentation */
    for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++)
      putchar(' ');

    /* print directory or file name */
     printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);

    /* print subdirectories and files */
    if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
      char subpath[MAX_PATH_LEN];
      snprintf(subpath, MAX_PATH_LEN, "%s/%s", path, entry->d_name);
      print_tree(subpath, indent + 4);
    }
  }

  closedir(dir);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


    char path[MAX_PATH_LEN] = "";

  if (argc > 1) {
    /* use specified directory */
    strncpy(path, argv[1], MAX_PATH_LEN);
    printf("%s\n",path);
  } else {
    /* use current working directory */
    getcwd(path, MAX_PATH_LEN);
    printf(".\n");
  }

  //printf(".\n");
  print_tree(path, 4);
  // You're on your own!

  return(0);
}
```

I initialized the char path [MAX_PATH_LEN] = ""; to an empty string
So that while calling recursively the code does not crash but still getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please go through the homework question guide - it may help you answer your own question.    https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: If you're able to use C++ you might want to and avoid a lot of the C string ugliness you'll otherwise have to deal with.

Comment: @tadman ugly strings :) a good one

Comment: I cannot reproduce this segfault in a fairly *normal* environment (8MB program stack, `./tree ~`). If the testing environment is of limited resources, recursively stack allocating 1KB might prove fatal with an exhaustive enough test. If that's the case, you might want to ditch the recursion and approach this iteratively.

Comment: One edge case is that when `strlen(argv[1]) == MAX_PATH_LEN`, `strncpy(path, argv[1], MAX_PATH_LEN);` fails to null-terminate the buffer.

Comment: Just a hint: you don't ever need multiple paths to exist at once, at all. With neither automatic nor dynamic lifetime. Just think about the relationship between a parent path and its child.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the segmentation fault when I simply compile and execute in bash. I don't know how Gradescope is working, but I imagine it does not use the same environment as classic bash...
The stack usage could be a problem: 1KiB by directory level.
Could you try to store the `subpath` area on the heap to check if it fixes the issue.

```
...

/* print subdirectories and files */
if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
  char *subpath = malloc(MAX_PATH_LEN);
  snprintf(subpath, MAX_PATH_LEN, "%s/%s", path, entry->d_name);
  print_tree(subpath, indent + 4);
  free(subpath);
}

...
```

Note: there is a better implementation for that, but it is the simplest way to check if you have a stack issue.

Comment: After trying this 1.8) Deep directory tree (0/5)
Test Failed: Program timed out after 5 seconds

Comment: On which directory did you test? Do you have a timeout in a small directory tree?

Answer (score 0):

SEGFAULT is likely the result of *stack overflow* caused by a deep hierarchy of directories being tested and the code's allocation of a 1Kb stack buffer for each level of recursion. And we don't know how the `DIR` struct of each level is allocated and released. Regardless, there's no need to preserve a separate copy of "the path so far" at each level.

Use only **one** buffer to build the hierarchical paths passed down to the next recursion. First, determine the end of the current path's string before entering the loop:

```
    char *pathEnd = path + strlen( path ); // ptr to '\0' so far
    unsigned remain = MAX_PATH_LEN - (pathEnd - path); // remaining space in buffer

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
```

Then, inside the loop, put the name(s) of any subdirectories at that same location:

```
if ( entry->d_type == DT_DIR ) {
    snprintf( pathEnd, remain, "/%s", entry->d_name ); // append "/childDirName"
    print_tree( path, indent + 4 ); // pass full path to next level
}
```

For good measure, use a bigger (single) buffer:

```
#define MAX_PATH_LEN 4096
```

Finally, replace the 2x magic number 4 with a token:

```
#define INDENT 4 // use this
```